# 4月 pitch accent

Tags: pitch-accent

NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 lists 4月 as either しがつガ{LHHL} or しがつガ{LHHH}, but is しがつ{HLL} also said?

Examples: [1](https://youtu.be/S8l5r2i8bhw?t=233), [2](https://youtu.be/KqiSp0ZFCaE?t=3353), [3](https://youtu.be/FMi0b62yd0g?t=282), [4](https://youtu.be/w-Dk147jJ_M)

Comment: I can’t believe NHK lists 平板 as correct for those month names. I don’t think I’ve ever heard it even from NHK announcers.

Comment: FYI https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/049.html

Comment: @aguijonazo It only lists them as heiban for their adverbial usage. 「４月行われる伝統行事」

Comment: @DariusJahandarie - Check [this](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典/suffix/がつ) out.

Comment: @aguijonazo Ah, that's because sakura-paris is a rip of NHK 1998. The heiban noun entries were removed from NHK 2016.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, even though NHK prescribes that にがつが{LHHL}, しがつが{LHHL}, ごがつが{HLLL}, くがつが{HLLL} are correct accent, にがつ{HLL}, しがつ{HLL} are also heard, that effectively regularize all 3-mora month names in 頭高型.

In my observation, this type of accentuation is mostly heard when the speaker refers to a specific date, presumably intending to make the number sound more salient. It is less likely to appear when you talk about, say, [『四月は君の嘘』](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E6%9C%88%E3%81%AF%E5%90%9B%E3%81%AE%E5%98%98).